# struts2 session timeout relogin to last visited page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

My application is developed using Struts2 and i have an interceptor that validates if the user is logged on or not based on a session attribute. Now lets say the session is timeout and the user tries to login again. Once the login is successful how can i handle relogin users and direct the user back to the last page they where working on...say page3.jsp??

loginInterceptor is

```
 public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
  @Override
   public String intercept(final ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

   String userLoggedin = (String) session.get("userLoggedin ");
    Object action = invocation.getAction();

    // user is not logged in yet
    if(userLoggedin == null){       


        // public pages that dont require login
        if (action instanceof LoginNotRequired) {
              return invocation.invoke();

        }

        // Pages that require the user to be logged in - user not logged in yet
        if (!(action instanceof LoginAction)) {
             return "loginRedirect";

        }       

    }

    // user is logged in
    if (userLoggedin.equals("true")) {
         return invocation.invoke();

    }

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

}

struts.xml definition

```
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="login" class="com.mypackage.LoginInterceptor">                
             </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="login"></interceptor-ref>
             <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"></default-interceptor-ref>

    <global-results>
        <result name="loginRedirect" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to persist the information across session removal. This means either a `user id/name` => `last page` map in application scope, a DB, etc. and an interceptor that keeps this information up-to-date based on the user's last request.

You could potentially keep this information on the client as well, like in a cookie.

Login would simply check for the presence of said data and redirect to it if found.

There are a lot of potential issues with this. For example, if the user's workflow depended on having specific information in their session, that information is now gone, and would need to be restored.

Comment: Can you tell me how this interceptor would work?? how do i get the current users page info? how to i tell delete this userid->lastpage map from the appications scope after 5 hrs??